# Roots of a polynomial equation.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, real-numbers, roots-of-cubics

I have been solving the cubic polynomial equation. The simplest of this is

$x^3-1=0$

On solving this equation considering only the real values, I got only one solution i.e

$x=1$

But a cubic polynomial equation has atleast 3 roots(may be complex).
I came to realise that the other roots are

$x=\frac{-1±i\sqrt{3}}{2}$

What the point is I got this from considering the x values as complex numbers.

When I try to rewrite the equation in terms of complex variable, this turns into

$z^3-1=0\\z=x+iy\\(x+iy)^3-1=0\\x^3-3xy^2-1 + i(3x^2y-y^3)=0\\$

On equating this to RHS.

REAL PART

$x^3-3xy^2=1$

IMAGINARY PART

$3x^2y-y^3=0$

On solving this imaginary part I get three solutions.

$y=0,±\sqrt{3}x$

When I substitute these into the real part equation.

I get the another equation as follows.

First one $y=0$

The equation is $x^3=1$

This has solution 1

Second and third are $±\sqrt{3}x$

$x^3-9x^3-1=0\\-8x^3=1\\x=\frac{-1}{2}$

So the roots are
$1,\frac{-1±i\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Is this a coincidence or any theorem or method.please anyone can explain me what's happened.

Here is what happened when I plot the functions in 3D plotter.
[Here is plotted function of real part and imaginary part](https://photos.app.goo.gl/pdecxFmt7Gz2RXft9)

When I looked the 3D plot from the top(only the curves of the surfaces when the xy plane cut the surface at $z=0$), [this is what I saw](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Bnb5fEDLZkzXQfeM7)

The intersection points of the surfaces (imaginary part and real part) and the xy plane are the roots of the equation
$z^3-1=0$

Comment: The equation $x^n-1=0$ is easy to solve in complex numbers. The roots are called the "roots of unity", and are given by $x=e^{2\pi m i/k}$.

Comment: Yes I know. I have also come across the equations of type $x^3 -x^2 -1=0$. These are solved using the above method. But I am asking what is the reason behind this.

Comment: $\frac{-1 \pm i \sqrt{3}}{2}$. You left out the $i$.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning it.

Comment: Galois Theory describes techniques for finding the roots of all polynomials up to and including fourth powers. There are all kinds of books with titles like "Abstract Algebra" that discuss this topic.

Comment: Oh.. thank you..sir 

Comment: Another way to handle this is to note that $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, so one root of $x^3-1=0$ is obviously $x=1$. What's left is the quadratic $x^2+x+1=0$ which can be solved with the quadratic formula. So in this specific case it's simple enough to find the roots without assuming the form $x+i y$.

Comment: @JayaGuru "*Is this a coincidence*" $-$ No coincidence, just two ways to solve the same equation.

Comment: @dxiv thank you 